# Regarding casting -1 to size_t leading to a stuck loop

Tags: c, size-t

an interview question on glassdoor is as follows. With my knowledge, it is hard to deduce anything out of it. What could be an appropriate question?

> A macro that computes a size_t number. Putting in a loop, it casts -1
>   to a size_t number, making the loop impossible to start.

as suggested by Michael Aaron Safyan, following might be the case

operates in the reverse:

> for (size_t i = 0; i > ((size_t) -1); i--) {}

For explanation see the answer

Comment: Deleting it, give me a few minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `size_t` is unsigned, so casting -1 to it will produce the maximum-valued `size_t`. One would fix this case by using a signed type (such as `int` or `ssize_t`).

Comment: so there might be a loop that would be casting it to -1 (i.e. multiplying it with -1) that would take it to its maximum value thus stopping the loop..kind of correct?

Comment: A more common bug I see with something like this is iterating backwards: for (size_t i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) { ... }. In those cases, the loop never terminates. But I could imagine something that operates in the reverse: for (size_t i = 0; i > ((size_t) -1); i--) {}.